# In comments you should be able to post code that then pops up on mouse over

Tags: feature-request, comments

to avoid comments like the sixth one on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319849/how-can-i-convert-a-text-file-outline-list-into-a-recursive-collection-of-objects/2319876#2319876)

Answer (score 5):

Really, Vlad should have just edited his answer to correspond to the edit you made to your question. I've done so now...

Comment: I agree, the issue was not a problem with the system.

Comment: ... in this particular case.

Comment: @Brad: point being, we should avoid comments like that by discouraging them, not by making them more usable - even if the code was displayed properly in a tooltip, you'd still have to expand the comments *and* hover over the 6th one in order to view it, while an edit to the question allows instant viewing, copying, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really keen on the idea of encouraging codes within comments, short inline ones are fine with me though.

And you wouldn't want a pop-up/tooltip that is longer/taller than your browser view port.